# Remove Airdrop function to do tightening of OSX

Tags: macos, security, airdrop

Could you tell me how to remove [Airdrop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AirDrop) function to do tightening of OSX?

Looks somebody accessing my Mac via AirDrop. I would like to remove the function. 
Please tell me how to remove the function except for not to turn off.

Comment: What have you already tried so far to remove Airdrop functionality?

Comment: AirDrop is 40kb file + all associated 100 kb, so total 150 kb ! a drop in a bucket for your disk.

Comment: I've not tried to remove it. what I used this "defaults write com.apple.NetworkBrowser DisableAirDrop ‑bool YES"

Comment: @user3171796 that would disable it not remove it.

Answer (score 2):

I did some looking around and came up with that the removing the AirDrop will give you only 150kb of space.

So I am not sure it is wort messing around with it, since I do not know what dependencies are there, and the disk space gain is not worth mentioning it.

You can look it up in your

/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ShareKit.framework/Versions/A/PlugIns/AirDrop.sharingservice/Contents/MacOS

Comment: Thank you for your respond. What I would like to know is removing AirDrop function to keep more securely

Comment: AFAIK once disabled on your computer it can be only turned on, on your computer, so it is safe from outsiders using it.